# File-path not displaying on tkinter entry box

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, path

I've looked into multiple threads and I can't seem to find out why the stringVar is not displaying on the entry box, once the file has been selected. I can see the print(filePath.get()) has the selected file but entry box stays blank.

Can someone please help?

```
#import libraries

import os
import paramiko
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import sys

def getFilePath():
    file_selected = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select File")
    filePath.set(file_selected)
    print(filePath.get())

#-------------------------------GUI------------------------------

gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title("NetWizard 1.0")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(gui, width = 1000, height = 700)
gui.resizable(False, False)
tabControl.pack( expand = 1, fill ="both")
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
  
tabControl.add(tab1, text ='RUGGEDCOM', )
tabControl.add(tab2, text ='WESTERMO')


#--------------------------RUGGEDCOM WIDGET----------------------
filePath = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(gui, textvariable=filePath, width=1000)
entry1 = tk.Entry(tab1, width =  60)

label1 = Label(tab1, text="IP Address List Input:", font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'))

button1 = Button(tab1, text='Browse', command=getFilePath, font=("Arial", 10), width = 10, bg='#add8e6')


label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx = 15, pady=10, sticky = W)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=5)
button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky = W)

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not set your entry text value in your function. Supposedly after you get your file path, you should assign the file path text value into the entry.

You can do so by inserting this code into your codes.

```
entry1.insert(0, "Test Value")
```

Your codes:

```
def getFilePath():
    file_selected = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select File")
    filePath.set(file_selected)
    print(filePath.get())
    entry1.insert(0, filePath.get())
```

You can refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-the-default-text-of-tkinter-entry-widget/ .

Comment: Hey Joshua, just tried that and it didn't work. changing it to filePath returns the StringVariable register

Comment: Hey Amac, sorry about it, got confused with your question, edited my answer, the entry1 insert should be in the function

Comment: Thanks, odd as I did this in a different python script without that and it worked. This method seems more trustworthly